# Proving Trig/Calc Identity $\frac{1}{1-\sin(x)}=\frac{1+\sin x}{\cos(x)^2}$

Tags: trigonometry

Our Trigonometry class is currently working on Pythagorean properties and proving identities. For the most part it has been simplistic yet challenging until this problem popped up. Any help on it will be greatly appreciated!

[Problem Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG0hp.jpg)

Edit: Apologizes for the vertical picture. Realized the problem just after posting and my wifi is too slow atm for me to fix it easily.

Comment: You can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to transcribe your posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{1-\sin x}=\frac{1+\sin x}{\cos^2 x}$$
Working on the right side
$$\frac{1+\sin x}{\cos^2 x}\left(\frac{1-\sin x}{1-\sin x}\right)=\frac{1-\sin^2x}{\cos^2x(1-\sin x)}=\frac{\cos^2x}{\cos^2x(1-\sin x)}=\frac{1}{1-\sin x}$$

Comment: Thanks for the speedy and clear answer!

Answer (score 5):

You start from
RHS = $\frac{1+sin(x)}{cos^2(x)}$ = $\frac{1+sin(x)}{1-sin^2(x)}$ = $\frac{1+sin(x)}{(1+sin(x))(1-sin(x))}$ = $\frac{1}{(1-sin(x))}$ = LHS

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $cos^2 x=1-sin^2 x$. Can you finish?

Comment: MathJax tip: write `\sin(x)` to render $\sin(x)$, instead of `sin(x)` to render $sin(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Cross multiplying will also give an identity, albeit a different one...

$$\frac {1}{1-\sin x} = \frac {1+\sin x}{\cos^2 x}$$
$$\Rightarrow \cos^2 x = (1-\sin x)(1+\sin x)$$
$$\Rightarrow \cos^2 x = (1-\sin^2 x)$$

and as $1 - \sin^2 x = \cos^2 x$, we have the result
$$\Rightarrow \cos^2 x = \cos^2 x \checkmark$$

Alternatively, we can also bring over $\sin^2 x$ which gives us the fundamental Pythagorean identity

$$\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1.$$